# How to initialize const members of structs on the heap

Tags: c

I would like to allocate a structure on the heap, initialize it and return a pointer to it from a function. I'm wondering if there's a way for me to initialize const members of a struct in this scenario:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  const int x;
  const int y;
} ImmutablePoint;

ImmutablePoint * make_immutable_point(int x, int y)
{
  ImmutablePoint *p = (ImmutablePoint *)malloc(sizeof(ImmutablePoint));
  if (p == NULL) abort();
  // How to initialize members x and y?
  return p;
}
```

Should I conclude from this that it is impossible to allocate and initialize a struct on the heap which contains const members?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Like so:

```
ImmutablePoint *make_immutable_point(int x, int y)
{
  ImmutablePoint init = { .x = x, .y = y };
  ImmutablePoint *p = malloc(sizeof *p);

  if (p == NULL) abort();
  memcpy(p, &init, sizeof *p);

  return p;
}
```

(Note that unlike C++, there is no need to cast the return value of `malloc` in C, and it is often considered bad form because it can hide other errors).

Comment: Note that the use of .x and .y in the init initialization is C99, you of course can use unamed entries if your compiler does not support it.

Comment: Standard says: (6.7.3) *If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use
of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.* and in undefined behaviour section: *An attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through
use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type (6.7.3).* That would make this example exhibit ub. What is your opinion?

Comment: @self.: The object that is pointed to by the pointer returned here is never actually defined, since it is created by `malloc()`.  Consider that `p` could just as well be defined as `void *p;` instead, with both instances of `sizeof *p` changed to `sizeof init`.

Comment: @caf Yes your version is correct, my comment was made before I came to that realization. As far as I know this is the only legal way to initialize a const type with allocated memory.

Comment: Can this memcpy be optimised away by the compiler? I can see this getting expensive for repeated allocations of large structs.

Comment: @Ephemera: Yes, it can - gcc on x86-64 using the lowest level of optimisation will compile the above function into one that does not call `memcpy()`.  That said, once you're calling `malloc()`, the `memcpy()` is not likely to be a concern.

Comment: @caf: As I understand, before expression `malloc(sizeof *p)`, the variable `p` is undefined.  Instead, should it be `malloc(sizeof init)` or `malloc(sizeof ImmutablePoint)`?

Comment: @kevinarpe: It does not matter, because `sizeof` explicitly does not evaluate its argument, so the behaviour of the expression is still defined.

Comment: @caf True, except if used with a variable length array (in C99).

Answer (score 12):

If this is C and not C++, I see no solution other than to subvert the type system.

```
ImmutablePoint * make_immutable_point(int x, int y)
{
  ImmutablePoint *p = malloc(sizeof(ImmutablePoint));
  if (p == NULL) abort();

  // this 
  ImmutablePoint temp = {x, y};
  memcpy(p, &temp, sizeof(temp));

  // or this
  *(int*)&p->x = x;
  *(int*)&p->y = y;

  return p;
}
```

Comment: If this is C, casting the return value of `malloc` is unnecessary and redundant.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on keeping the const in the structure, you are going to have to do some casting to get around that:

```
int *cheat_x = (int *)&p->x;
*cheat_x = 3;
```

Comment: Doesn't that invoke undefined behaviour?

Comment: If you allocated the memory, I think it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I like [caf's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219001/how-to-initialize-const-members-of-structs-on-the-heap/2219034#2219034), but this occured to me too

```
ImmutablePoint* newImmutablePoint(int x, int y){ 
   struct unconstpoint {
      int x;
      int y;
   } *p = malloc(sizeof(struct unconstpoint));
   if (p) { // guard against malloc failure
      *p.x = x;
      *p.y = y;
   }
   return (ImmutablePoint*)p;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the const here.  Can you please explain?

Comment: @KCArpe: I allocate and assign a `struct` that is identical in structure to `ImmutablePoint` but is mutable, then cast the pointer in the return statement so that the mutable version is never visible to the user. It's a fairly standard abuse of casting to "break" the type system. The disadvantage of this relative caf's solution is that it is not [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t%5Frepeat%5Fyourself): if someone edits `ImmutablePoint` I need to edit `unconstpoint` as well.

Comment: also, to avoid the issue with someone changing the size of ImmutablePoint, it may be best to add an `assert(sizeof(ImmutablePoint) == sizeof(struct uconstpoint));` though the compiler is also allowed to make them different.