# Could this memcpy result in undefined behavior?

Tags: c, struct, constants, language-lawyer

With this definition:

```
struct vector {
    const float x;
    const float y;
};
```

would the code snippet below possibly result in undefined behavior?

```
struct vector src = {.x=1.0, .y=1.0};
struct vector dst;
void *dstPtr = &dst;    
memcpy(dstPtr, &src, sizeof dst);
```

`gcc` and `clang` do not emit any warnings, but it does result in modification of a const-qualified type.

The construct looks a lot like the one given in the accepted answer to [How to initialize const members of structs on the heap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2219034/1380680)
, which apparently is conformant. I do not understand how my example would therefore be non-conformant.

Comment: Can you be more precise about which part you think could invoke undefined behavior? I don't see anything suspicious

Comment: See OP's last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242966/is-this-usage-of-the-const-keyword-in-line-with-its-intention

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/222457/is-it-a-good-idea-to-const-qualify-the-fields-of-structure-in-c

Comment: With the other answer there, this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this usage of the const keyword in line with its intention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242966/is-this-usage-of-the-const-keyword-in-line-with-its-intention)

Comment: @SergeyA The other question seemed too broad and long, I realized that when I read the responses. This question here focuses on the non-opinion part. I may close one or the other later, but at this point I believe they address different questions.

Comment: A `struct` that has a `const` member can _not_ be set by _assignment_, only by _initialization_ (which you do for `src`). The `memcpy` is similar to assignment. Remove the `const` from within the `struct` and things will be fine. IMO, `const` on struct members is not so useful because of the very problem you're encountering. Note that the `memcpy` won't harm anything even with `const`, but it's bad practice.

Comment: @CraigEstey it can harm. Consider the code - `{struct vector foo={...}; float a = foo.x ;memcpy(&foo, ..., sizeof(foo)); int b = foo.x;}`. The compiler can reuse the value of `a` to set `b`.

Comment: Would you expect a compiler warning if the `void *` pointer was passed to another function which in turn called `memcpy`? How far away from the `const` would you expect the compiler to analyse?

Comment: Continuing, leaving off `const` on struct _members_, [again, IMO] a better use of `const` would be on a pointer to [or instance of] the `struct` (e.g. `const struct vector *vec_nochangeme_ptr = &src;` or `const struct vector src = { ... };`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I guess by "harm", I should have said segfault. But, here, `dst` is unitialized until after the `memcpy`

Comment: @WeatherVane Good question... I think it would be appropriate to emit a warning at the moment of `void *dstPtr = &dst;`. But it should accept `const void *dstPtr = &dst;`. Just thinking out loud.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Your example made it all clear to me. Would you mind promoting it to an answer?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that question "Is it a good idea to const-qualify the fields of structure in C?" is related. I know that the suggested opaque pointers are a common approach, but for this particular case I do not like the create/destroy semantics associated with that. Having the instances on the stack is more appealing.

Comment: Seems like a good question, not sure why anyone downvoted it (although the last paragraph is unnecessary)

Comment: @M.M Thanks. I added the last paragraph because SO instructed me to motivate why this is not a duplicate (it was flagged as such). I have not asked many questions before so am still learning...

Comment: I do not understand why this question got downvoted; It's a legitime and well formulated question, and I don't think that it is straight forward to answer.

Comment: Unfortunately there's a handful of people who seem determined to close every question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `const`-qualifiers on members let the compiler assume that - after an object has been initialized - these members must not be altered through any way, and it may optimise code accordingly (cf, for example, @Ajay Brahmakshatriya comment).

So it is essential to distinguish the *initialization* phase from the subsequent phases where *assignments* would apply, i.e. from when on may a compiler assume that an object got initialized and has an effective type to rely on.

I think there is a main difference between your example and that in the accepted answer you cited. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2219034/2630032) SO answer, the target aggregate object with const-qualified member types is created through `malloc`:

```
ImmutablePoint init = { .x = x, .y = y };
ImmutablePoint *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
memcpy(p, &init, sizeof *p);
```

According to the rules on how a stored value of an object may be accessed (cf. this part of [an online c standard draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6)), the `p`-target object will get its effective type the first time in the course of performing `memcpy`; the effective type is then that of the source object `init`, and the first `memcpy` on an object that got `malloced` can be seen as an initialization. Modifying the target object's const members afterwards, however, would be UB then (I think that even a second `memcpy` would be UB, but that's probably opinion based).

> **6.5 Expressions**
>
> 6. The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object, if any.87) ... **If a value is
>      copied into an object having no declared type using memcpy** or memmove,
>      or is copied as an array of character type, **then the effective type of
>      the modified object for that access and for subsequent accesses that
>      do not modify the value is the effective type of the object from which
>      the value is copied**, if it has one. For all other accesses to an
>      object having no declared type, the effective type of the object is
>      simply the type of the lvalue used for the access.
>
> **87) Allocated objects have no declared type.**

In your example, however, the target object `dst` already has a declared type through it's definition `struct vector dst;`. Hence, the const-qualifiers on `dst`'s members are already in place before the `memcpy` is applied, and it has to be seen as an assignment rather than an initialization.

So I'd vote for UB in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that is an interesting citation and seems to explain it indeed. However, I have a problem interpreting "an object having no declared type". Isn't `p` declared as `ImmutablePoint *`?

Comment: I don't think so; `p` is a different object than that to which it points; `p` has the declared type `ImmutablePoint *`, but the object to which it points has  not even been created.

Comment: OK, it was not entirely clear to me what 'object' meant in this context. I also found in [7.22.3.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.4) "The malloc function allocates space for an *object* whose size is specified by size and whose value is indeterminate.", and I suppose, its type is then indeterminate too.

Comment: I would like to still add that in this code - `foo(const char* t) {char s = *t; some_function_call(t); char r = *t;}`, the compiler cannot optimize the second read even if `t`, is marked to be pointing to a `const` qualified `char`. This is because `t` might not be originally pointing to a `const` object and it is perfectly valid for `some_function_call` to modify the contents. But this case is special because the `const` is inside the struct. Any pointer's field will always be `const`.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek objects allocated by `malloc` have no type yet.  They can have *effective type* set by writes into the object.