Make compilers not compile indirect calls
I have the following hashmap:
typedef uint32_t (*HashFuncPointer)(uint32_t key);
typedef bool     (*KeyComparisonFunc)(uint32_t key1, uint32_t key2);

typedef struct Hashmap {
    void* items;
    uint64_t max_size;
    uint64_t count;
    uint64_t value_size;
    HashFuncPointer hash_func;
    KeyComparisonFunc key_comparison_func;
} Hashmap;

This hashmap has it's hash_func set during initialisation and is never changed afterwards. However, calling these function pointers within my hashmap functions compiles to indirect calls:
uint32_t example_func(Hashmap* map) {
    uint32_t value = map->hash_func(123);
    return value;
}

Using GCC 14.2 for x86_64, compiles into:
example_func:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+40] // <--- Want to avoid this
        mov     edi, 123
        jmp     rax

Obviously, my example_func doesn't know what the map being passed uses as its hash_func, so it indirectly calls it, but this is preventing optimization/inlining. This kind of sucks since the function a hashmap is using should always be known at compile time. C++ has constexpr for this, and similarly in C++ I can set the function pointer to be a constant. But in C, if you try to assign the value of a const member variable of a struct allocated on the heap, it is an error at worst, and, from my understanding, undefined behaviour at best. Is there a way to solve this without having to create a seperate struct each time I want my hashmap to have a different hash function?

"this is preventing optimization/inlining." --> Doubtful. prevents significant overall optimization. The hash function itself is likely many times slower.  IMO, premature optimization here.  Code for clarity and do not spend your valuable time with such small matters.

"Obviously, my example_func doesn't know what the map being passed uses as it's hash_func, so it indirectly calls it" i.e. there's no way to avoid an indirect call.

"This kind of sucks since the function a hashmap is using should always
be known at compile time."
If it is known compile time and it does not change why do you want to use pointers to functions?

if its known at compile time, why the pointer and not just hardcoding the function call?

@dbush I was talking more from a code perspective. The compiler knows very well what the map being passed uses as its hash function, yet despite this it doesn't inline the function. If I mark the code pointer as const, it actually does inline the call, but again, declaring const fields for heap allocated structs seems to be undefined behaviour.

@0___________ Because if I have 2 different hashmaps, one which uses a string hash and one which uses a value hash, I would have to create a new identical file .c to compile and change the struct name and function, which feels kind of overkill. I ideally want my code to be reusable

And if you have two different hashmaps, you'll need indirect calls.

You are not saying that C++ produces better code than C, are you? :-)  In C you probably need example_func_type1 and example_func_type2 and call different functions for different hash types. That makes it a compile time choice and not a runtime decision. Note that in C++ it is a template.

"If I mark the code pointer as const, it actually does inline the call" Can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/oaYrTzxEj

C would have you use macros to eliminate the repetition/duplication of text.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219001/how-to-initialize-const-members-of-structs-on-the-heap regarding initializing heap-allocated structs with const members.

Want to avoid this Why?  What actual evidence do you have that an indirect call has any measurable performance impact?

@AndrewHenle: As the OP says, it's not just the difference between call [mem] vs. call rel32, it's that it prevents the hash function from inlining and e.g. keeping integer constants in registers across hashing multiple items.  It's very plausible that you could measure at least a few percent difference in a loop hashing many integers, at least in a microbenchmark.  Maybe even more significant.  Also, indirect calls get extra expensive  for use-cases that harden them against Spectre (e.g. in a kernel or maybe a sandboxing VM like a JVM), -mindirect-branch=thunk, but OP isn't doing that

The compiler knows very well what the map being passed uses as its hash function, yet despite this it doesn't inline the function. - your [mcve] doesn't show that.  You're showing a stand-alone definition for example_func not inlined into a caller that sets hash_func to a known value.  There isn't a definition present anywhere of a hash function, or any code that sets that member in a struct, so impossible for a compiler to do anything other than indirect call or tailcall with jmp.
